# Flurry User ID is it evil?

Tags: iphone, ios, flurry

So I recently added Flurry analytics to my app and I added the user Id equivalent with my in-app usernames. When I check flurry the data is not visibile to me. Ultimately I just wanted to see users that used the app the most but I can't seem a way to view this data.

Now, I'm exaggerating when I say Evil, but I don't really want to give usernames to Flurry just so they can store it. Is there any benefit to me on giving this data? What's your opinion? Obviously I want to respect my users privacy, is this violating that?

Comment: "Flurry shall own and retains all right, title and interest in and to Reports and all other results, data and/or information provided to you through the service (collectively, "Results"). You may use the Reports only in connection with your use of Flurry Analytics pursuant to this Agreement and not for any other purpose."    This is the reason we implemented our own Analytics. Do not pass any data that you do not want Flurry to use in anyway, because it can use it anyway.

Comment: Try AskingPoint.com. You can get that data. We don't want your user id's In fact we ask you NOT to send them to us... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user ID set on Flurry is available under the Events Logs section. The Flurry userId can be used to tie a user back to your internal systems. This userId will travel along with any event reporting that the Flurry Dev Portal provides. It is highly recommended to seek user permission before collecting any data for analytics. (Disclaimer: I work at Flurry)

Comment: Thanks for answering this old question. I'm actually not working with the project anymore but it's good to know.

Comment: @Aman Bansal, I didn't see any information under "Event" logs. As a matter of fact, there's no any event logs there, although I implemented something like: [Flurry setUserID:theUserID]; in the app. Do you know why?

Comment: @TonyXu: There's a reporting delay of upto 7 hours on the Flurry developer portal. New Events may take slightly longer to show up.

Comment: @Aman, thanks for getting back to me. My events is 24 hours now. However, I did not "create" or "register" any event, just has code setUserID:theUserID in my app. I do see an "uncaught event" in my event logs, is this uncaught one referring to my setUserID? In my code, I have this line of code, plus another two lines of "setValue withParameters timed". So supposed I have three kinds of events? The log says "add description to THIS event". I think it's only one event. Thanks again.

Comment: @TonyXu: The userID is simply tied to Events that you create inside your app. Unless you've created Events, you would see no Event Logs and hence no associated userID. I will send more details to your request on our Support desk.

Comment: Hi @AmanBansal is there any way to export Flurry event logs via API? here's an unanswered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016536/is-there-a-way-to-get-reported-user-id-from-flurry-api