# Is there a way to get reported User ID from Flurry API?

Tags: ios, api, flurry

I have an iOS game using Flurry, so I'm sending to Flurry unique IDs for each player trough [Flurry setUserID:@"USER_ID"] and after some hours I'm getting this ID's from "Flurry  Page >Events > Event Logs > Download CSV" to tie a user in my internal systems (as [Flurry User ID is it evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906169/flurry-user-id-is-it-evil) indicate); but this is a manual process and take a lot of time.

Is there a way to get this Event Logs from Flurry API? I'm currently using:

```
http://api.flurry.com/eventMetrics/Event?apiAccessCode=APIACCESSCODE&apiKey=APIKEY&startDate=STARTDATE&endDate=ENDDATE&eventName=EVENTNAME&versionName=VERSIONNAME
```

as Flurry indicates (http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=API/Code/EventMetrics) but this gives only a summary.

Thanks

Comment: have you ever found a way to retrieve it or had to switch to another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the Technical support, take a look at their answer

> Thank you for contacting Flurry Technical Support. I will be happy to
>   answer your questions.
>
> I'm afraid the raw data API is no longer available as it is being
>   phased out. Apologies for any inconvenience.
>
> **However, as an alternative to the raw data API we have introduced a
>   feature where you can download 100,000 rows of raw event logs from
>   under "Events-->Event Logs" on the left navigation. Just download
>   often so you don't miss anything.**
>
> The user ID on Flurry is available under the Events Logs section,
>   provided you've set it to be collected.
>
> The user ID is set using this code: FlurryAgent.setUserID(String);
>
> The Flurry userID can be used to tie a user back to your internal
>   systems. The userID will travel along with the user through out the
>   event logs. It is up to you to ensure that the userID is unique for
>   each individual user. It is highly recommended to seek user permission
>   before collecting any data for analytics.
>
> Please let me know if I can assist further.